# How can one troubleshoot Java Web Services?

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, debugging

How do I troubleshoot Web Services?

I have few Web Services Deployed on my local server (localhost) and I have Java Client application which calls them.

Of course, I can run my client in debug mode and set break points, but I don't know how to deal with Web Services?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [remote debugging](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/concepts/cremdbug.htm) to debug your web services. Set up a break point in the web service code and it will stop at the break point when it hits it. This [link](https://confluence.sakaiproject.org/display/BOOT/Setting+Up+Tomcat+For+Remote+Debugging) has a good tutorial on setting up tomcat and eclipse for remote debugging. I assumed you are using eclipse but I am sure other IDEs will have similar features.

There is also the [web service explorer](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/jst/components/ws/1.0/tutorials/WebServiceExplorer/WebServiceExplorer.html) tool in eclipse. If it's a JAX-WS webservice then [soapUI](http://www.soapui.org/) is a great tool for testing. If it's a JAX-RS then [rest-assured](http://code.google.com/p/rest-assured/) is a useful one.

Ofcourse there is always printing out debug messages in your log file if you prefer not to set up a debugger.

Comment: I use Axis2. Thanks a lot. I will try your link.